# Can you change your icon color in Spore?

Tags: spore

In Spore, tribal stage and beyond. You have an "icon color" of blue. Is there an option somewhere that lets you change this? I glanced over the game settings to no avail. In a game that lets you customize practically everything, it seems off that you can't change your icon color.

Answer (score 2):

The colour of your tribe/country/empire is mainly based on your creature's Coat colour (second layer). I do not believe it will change if you alter your creature afterwards, but at least you can control it before you enter the Tribal stage.

Comment: Didn't know that, I think my empie was green, and my creature was greenish too IIRC.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. My creature color was yellow/white yet my empire color was blue

Comment: I think it likes picking blue when it gets a colour it doesn't want, like white, grey, or black. I don't have enough experience to be sure; I only have one data point of a white coat that created a blue icon colour.

Answer (score 0):

From what other people said, I'm pretty sure its random, but there is a bug where if you start a new save game and get to tribal stage, your original save's color will match the new save.